# python not working raspberry on pi3+ (was working op old Pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

for a couple of months i was using the following script on my Raspberry Pi to read my meter (PVE system). Last week a bought a new Pi 3+. This script isn't working on this PI. It creates the "workfile" but it stays empty.

I don't get any errors so i don't know why it isn't working. When in attach the meter back to my old Pi, everything is working fine.

Can somebody help me to get this script working on my new PI? thx.

```
   #!/usr/bin/python

    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import datetime

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
workfile = '/var/log/gpio23-counter'

counter = 0
while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.RISING)
    # reading
    try:
        f = open(workfile, 'ab+')       # open for reading. If it does not exist, create it
        value = int(f.readline().rstrip())  # read the first line; it should be an integer value
    except:
        value = 0               # if something went wrong, reset to 0
    #print "old value is", value
    f.close()   # close for reading
    # writing
    f = open(workfile, 'w')
    f.write((str(value+1)+ '\n'))           # the value
    f.write((str(datetime.datetime.now())+ '\n'))   # timestamp
    f.close()

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Are you running the exact same version of Python on both Raspberry Pi's?

Comment: No, pi3 has a newer version. 2.7.13. Old 2.7.9. Is there a way to run the script with a previous version? Or downgrade ? Or change the script to run in the New version?

Comment: What does printing the value and printing the date return? Does writing it to your working directory (instead of /var/log/) work?

Comment: Already tried to change /var/log to home/pi/ but that doesnt make any different. When i used a script to read the data (so don't write to al log) is see it generates 10-15 lines a second. Is that normal?

Comment: Can you print the values/datetimes to your screen/terminal?

Comment: Counter is now 9.2295 kWh
Counter is now 9.23 kWh
Counter is now 9.2305 kWh
Counter is now 9.231 kWh
Counter is now 9.2315 kWh
Counter is now 9.232 kWh
Counter is now 9.2325 kWh
Counter is now 9.233 kWh
Counter is now 9.2335 kWh
Counter is now 9.234 kWh
Counter is now 9.2345 kWh
Counter is now 9.235 kWh
Counter is now 9.2355 kWh etcetera

Comment: When i fire the script without the sudo comment I get     f.close()   # close for reading
NameError: name 'f' is not defined